# gatsby-plugin-google-analytics allowing callback or setting a require option

Tags: google-analytics, gatsby

Is there a way to add a callback or a way to pass a require to gatsby-plugin-google-analytics ?
I have my gatsby-config setup with the plugin.

```
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics`,
      options: {
        trackingId: XXXXX,
        optimizeId: 'GTM-XXXXXX',
        head: true,
        anonymize: true,
      },
    },
```

This creates the following on my page.

```
  if (typeof ga === "function") {
    ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx', 'auto');
    ga('require', 'GTM-xxxxx'); 
  }
```

I'm looking for a way to add another require below the other one but I'm not seeing this option in the plugin.

The outcome should be

```
  if (typeof ga === "function") {
    ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx', 'auto');
    ga('require', 'GTM-Txxxxx');
    ga('require', 'GTM-Fxxxxxx')  
  }
```

Anyone know how I can do this through the plugin in gatsby ?

Answer (score 1):

The GA Gatsby plugin only allows you to add optimize and it has no option to include GTM.

You have to use "`gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager`".

Sample snippet from the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager/?=tag%20man)

```
// In your gatsby-config.js
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager`,
    options: {
      id: "YOUR_GOOGLE_TAGMANAGER_ID",

      // Include GTM in development.
      // Defaults to false meaning GTM will only be loaded in production.
      includeInDevelopment: false,

      // Specify optional GTM environment details.
      gtmAuth: "YOUR_GOOGLE_TAGMANAGER_ENVIROMENT_AUTH_STRING",
      gtmPreview: "YOUR_GOOGLE_TAGMANAGER_ENVIROMENT_PREVIEW_NAME",
    },
  },
]
```

Comment: So do you use both plugins gatsby-plugin-google-analytics and gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager ? I'm already adding GTM in html.js using   <script
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `
              window['dataLayer'] = [];(function(w, d, s, l, i) {w[l] = w[l] ||.........

Comment: If you have already added GTM in html.js then thats fine. No need to add anymore plugins. What I would suggest is to just use GTM plugin, then add a GA and  optimize tag via  GTM. This way one GTM plugin can do the work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. How would I add GA and optimize tag via GTM plugin ?

Comment: You need to login into GTM, and then add a tag from GTM UI. Find here : https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7164339?hl=en

Comment: Ok great so I could remove my gatsby-plugin-google-analytics plugin then ?

Comment: yep mate ! just check if there are no other dependencies in your code with that plugin. Otherwise its safe to remove and add GTM plugin :)